# Enable HTTPS and Set www.localhost as default application URL

Tags: php, apache

I need to access a web app via below URL:

```
https://www.localhost/index.php
```

Below is my Apache configuration:

```
ScriptAlias /www.localhost/ "/var/www/siva/scripts/"
Alias /pages/ "/var/www/siva/wpages/"
ServerName www.localhost
<Directory "/var/www/siva/scripts">
    AllowOverride None
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    Options None
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/siva/wpages">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
</Directory>
```

/var/www/siva/scripts/index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

If I access my page in a browser as URL:

```
http://localhost/www.localhost/index.php
```

it works fine but the same does not if I access as

```
http://www.localhost/index.php
```

What changes should I make to achieve the same and how can I make it available at "https" protocol only?

Comment: I'm not clear about what you are trying to achieve. If you want it to work only over HTTPS then isn't it not working when you access `http://www.localhost/index.php` desirable?

Comment: What does "not working fine" when you access `http://www.localhost/index.php` mean? What happens? Do you get an error? What error? A 404? A DNS lookup failure? Something else? What does the server error log say?

Comment: I am looking for right Apache config that would make my app be accessible at (-[https://www.localhost/index.php]-) - but with above configuration it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prakash, you need to add `ServerAlias` to make it work as `localhost` as well, and add *HTTPS* redirect, *RewriteRule*, as I understood, it's what you want, for example:

```
ScriptAlias /www.localhost/ "/var/www/siva/scripts/"
Alias /pages/ "/var/www/siva/wpages/"
ServerName www.localhost

ServerAlias localhost

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

[httpd *ServerAlias* Directive:](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ServerAlias)

> The ServerAlias directive sets the alternate names for a host, for use with name-based virtual hosts. The ServerAlias may include wildcards, if appropriate.

#### EDIT 1:

At first, after you edit *httpd's .conf* files restart your httpd, e.g: `service httpd restart`. You  can create [*VirtualHost*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#virtualhost) to workaround your problem:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>

   ServerName localhost
   ServerAlias www.localhost
   DocumentRoot /path/to/your/site/root

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Then do the same for SSL site:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>

   ServerName localhost
   ServerAlias www.localhost
   DocumentRoot /home/localhost  #path to your localhost root directory

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]      #rewrite all www to non-www
   RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /home/localhost/ssl.cert
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/localhost/ssl.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /home/localhost/ssl.bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

#### EDIT 2:

For *SSL* site you can change `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` (it could depend on your Linux distribution) but at the same time, there is no real need for that and you could just place your directives in *httpd.conf*.

Comment: I am getting the below error: Syntax error on line 65 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
ServerAlias only used in <VirtualHost>
httpd (no pid file) not running

Comment: Thanks - can you please let me know which file to change for 'SSL site'

Comment: I get this error - [Sat Apr 05 15:38:44 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Invalid method in request \x16\x03\x01
[Sat Apr 05 15:38:44 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Invalid method in request \x16\x03\x01

Comment: I modified the below file - /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl

Comment: Thanks - I checked and tried solution at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=806884 - it worked . Thanks

Comment: @Prakash Sorry, I was out! I'm glad you could figure this out!